# Will 1cm deep pinholes from critter guard cause a leak in modified bitumen flat roll roofing?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, roofing

When they installed the critter guard under my solar panels, they didn't trim back the sharp edges and in some areas up to 1cm of wire has penetrated my roof where this critter guard is pushed into my roof.

[image]

Should I be concerned about leaks?  This is a modified bitumen roof that is 8 years old and I think they ripped out whatever old roofing was underneath so this might be the only layer.  I haven't noticed any leaks or bubbles.

Will the asphalt roofing just melt and seal itself around these tiny penetrations?  I've noticed some parts of the critter guard have already completely sunk into the material so it's entire lengths.

Should I just slather on some wet patch along a 1" perimeter to be safe? If so, can I just put the wet patch on without the fiber reinforced fleece?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*I* would worry—the roll-out roofing is likely to be less than 1cm thick, so those wire ends would penetrate the roofing.  Trying the wet patch wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Would the wet patch require the fiber fleece and a second coat?

Answer (score 0):

A centimeter is is a pretty good distance into a roof. I'd be looking to fix it. The best solution in my humble opinion would be to cut/trim those areas where the roofing material is penetrated and then use some wet patch to fill in the holes. I wouldn't count on the roofing material sealing itself.

Comment: If I did the wet patch on top without cutting/trimming, do I need to put the fiber fleece on top as well?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey  No you don't need to.  Plus many wet patch brands have small fibers already mixed in with it.